# Background cuts off when html and body height are set to 100%

Tags: css, background-image

I have my html and body set to 100% height, and a background image set on body, which gets cut off when scrolling down, as shown below.

[image]

However, YouTube has 100% height on html and body, and a background on body, and it stretches to the full height of the content. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this a background color or image?

Comment: Is that really an image? Is there some reason you couldn't simply use a color? The `100%` gets read when the DOM loads so basically 100% means 100% of the window height, not 100% of the content. There's also the background-cover CSS option. Show some code... there may be some solutions.

Comment: Yes, there's an image. CSS can be found here: http://cdn.crayze.com/css/photocrayze.css

Comment: Seriously? How about posting the relevant code for the body and background rather than asking us to weed through the minified version? In any event, remove the height from the body tag and your image will tile completely. Is there some other reason you want or need the body set to 100%?

Comment: Well the reason for the 100% height was to get the background to stretch all the way to the bottom if the page height was less than the browser viewport height, otherwise the background doesn't stretch to the bottom for that case either. I thought I'd post the full code in case anything that it inherited prior to the relevant code made any difference. There are also online tools to unminify: http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/

Comment: :) I know there are online tools to un-minify.. but should others have to use tools to help you? Seriously, help us help you! I don't understand your comments on "stretch" regarding the background. Youve' got no code to alter the size. You may simply need to add the proper `background-repeat` statement to the CSS. A tile should tile completely and not be cutoff regardless of scrolling. http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/wG7h8/

Comment: I tried replicating the problem in jsFiddle but I can't seem to do it. Here's a link to the full html of the page so you can take a look in Inspector (if you're using Chrome/Safari): http://edge.crayze.com:8080/photos/upload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the **only** reason you put the 100% height is for the background (as one of your comments seems to suggest), then just change that to `min-height: 100%` and you should have no issues. You will have 100% height on short pages, but expand to as much as you need on longer pages.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend an image unless you know the exact total height. The background image is "Extended" to the bottom. Often  websites make use of an image that slowly "fades" to a solid color and then the background is set to that solid color.

Another common solution is to mark the background image as fixed so that way it doesn't scroll and thus always shows as expected.

The 100% height on the body is a scam... 8-) It generally represents 100% of the window, not the body.

Answer (score 0):

A background-image will not automatically stretch to fill its container. If you want to create a 'continuous' background, you should use either the repeat-y property (which makes the image repeat vertically), set a background-position: fixed or, in the case of a solid colour, just set a coloured background.

In your case, it looks like your background is a solid colour. Might I suggest just using a plain background colour? It makes your CSS easier to read and change, and it also saves your server some bandwidth.