# background repeat with html,body height to 100% with css sticky footer

Tags: html, css, background-image, sticky-footer

## Problem

I'm using [this](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) implementation of a CSS sticky footer. It does:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

I use (would like to) use a repeating background, however, the `height:100%` causes this issue:
[image] (image from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696911/background-cuts-off-when-html-and-body-height-are-set-to-100) sticky footer question with unsatisfactory answers)

It's my understanding that the image gets sized to the size of the window at rendering, and thus never sizes past that.

## Question

Is it possible to continue to use my existing choice of CSS sticky footer with a repeating background image rendered completely on long pages

OR

is there another option of CSS sticky footers which does support the repeating background?

#### For reference

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">Header text</div>
    <div id="main">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer Text</div>
```

CSS

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 180px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */
#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 180px;
    clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add additional wrapper. At least I always do exactly that. And attach bg-image to div#no-footer, it will stretch to the bottom

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    background-image:url(...) top left repeat-x;
}
#no-footer-pad {
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#footer {
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

html markup:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
         <div id="no-footer-pad"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

So you have almost this markup, you must simply add additional div (`#no-footer-pad`), so that your content would not overlap footer

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to position fixed for this sticky footer as like this

```
.footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
height:xxxx;
}
```

Comment: This provides for a nice fixed footer, but I'd like my fixed to the bottom and not scrolling with the screen. Cheers.