# Container Div overflow gets clipped when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, overflow

So I'm making an Electron app with HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have a container div called #mainGrid which serves as a CSS grid container. It has 100% height so the background color stays centered and covers top to bottom:
[screencap of starting screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpNPI.png)
 
It works fine until the dynamically added content causes overflow, then when you scroll down the container div and its background are clipped:
 
[screencap of clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvtmj.png)
I've included a screencap of the DevTools highlighting the #mainGrid and showing the clipping at the bottom as well:
[screencap of DevTools Highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPSHk.png)
I have discovered that resizing the window will make the div "catch up" to 100% height again but it should just STAY 100%, right? I'm at my wits end on this one. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's my current CSS:

```
html, body {
    background-color: rgb(96, 174, 238); 
    margin: 0px;  
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*----Main grid area ----*/
#mainGrid {
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    border-style: none groove none groove;
    margin: 0 100px 0 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid: 'appHeader settingsDiv'
        'products products'
        'addProdBtn grandTotals';
    align-content: start;
}
```

If any additional code would be helpful too please let me know. Thanks!

edit: Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/main.css">
    <title>Ultimate Quoting Tool 9000!!!</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="mainGrid">

            <div id="appHeader">
                <h1>Quoting Tool 9000!!!</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="settingsDiv">
                <a href="" id="settingsBtn">Settings</a>
            </div>

            <ul id="quoteList">
                <li class="prodGrid">
                    <div class="prodHead">
                        <label>Substrates:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prodBody">
                        <select>
                            <option>Coroplast</option>
                            <option>Sintra</option>
                            <option>Dibond</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dimenHead">
                        <label>Dimensions:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dimenBody">
                        <label>Length:</label>
                        <input type="text" size="2">
                        <label>Width:</label>
                        <input type="text" size="2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="unitsHead">
                        <label>Units:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="unitsBody">
                        <select>
                            <option>cm</option>
                            <option>mm</option>
                            <option>ft</option>
                            <option>in</option>
                            <option>yd</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qtyHead">
                        <label>Qty:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qtyBody">
                        <input type="text" size="2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pricingHead">
                        <label>Pricing:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select>
                            <option>Regular</option>
                            <option>Trade</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="totalHead">
                        <label>Total:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="totalBody">
                        <p>$1999.99</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="notes">
                        <label class="notes">Notes:</label>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="addProduct">
                <a href="" id="addProductBtn">Add Product</a>
            </div>

            <div id="grandTotals">
                <p>Subtotal: <br />
                    GST/Taxes: <br />
                    Discounts: <br />
                    Grand Total: <br />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span id="subtotalVal">$1999.99</span><br />
                    <span id="taxVal">$100.00</span><br />
                    <span id="discountsVal">$0.00</span><br />
                    <span id="grandTotalVal">$2099.99</span>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: HTML will be needed. It seems like the Amount section is not a part of the #mainGrid. WIll need the HTML markup to confirm.

Comment: @DumbCoder7 added :)

Comment: I have also added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg I fixed it!
So, I had to change "height" on my #mainGrid to "min-height"..
Also worth noting, had to keep the height attribute in html and body tags as well since they're the parent, and a margin = 0px, so the #mainGrid would stretch to the top and bottom. Here's the new working css:

```
html, body {
    background-color: rgb(96, 174, 238); 
    margin: 0px; 
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

/*----Main grid area ----*/
#mainGrid {
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    border-style: none groove none groove;
    margin: 0 100px 0 100px;
    display: grid;
    grid: 'appHeader settingsDiv'
        'products products'
        'addProdBtn grandTotals';
    align-content: start;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I should mention I had the breakthrough after finding this thread:
[Background cuts off when html and body height are set to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696911/background-cuts-off-when-html-and-body-height-are-set-to-100)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the properties: `min-height:100%; height:100%` from `html,body` in the CSS section. Should work well.

```
html, body {
    background-color: rgb(96, 174, 238); 
    margin: 0px;  

    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That DOES fix the clipping issue. However, now the #mainGrid doesn't fit 100% height of the window on startup.. Any thoughts on how to achieve that without the clipping?

Comment: Then maybe try `height:100vh` in the #mainGrid Css, if that's what you want. You might have to change it `90vh` or so, if you have a header.

Comment: So 100vh works at the start, but then the same issue.. Once the content overflows down scrolling down clips the #mainGrid and it's background, but not the inner content.. Also resizing the window a little will cause the #mainGrid height to "catch up" and fill 100vh again.. So wierd!